# Why doesn't Java expose a Compile time reflection based toString/hashCode/equals?

Tags: java, reflection, compilation

If I understand it correct, it should cost nothing in addition to actual function processing  (of toString/hashCode/equals), if Java could compute the functions for the object for which compile-time reflection is requested.

For the cases when objects are up/down casted the behavior is still better than pointer address as toString representation, which practically is useless.

Something like

```
// Returns the compile time 'ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(foo)'
foo.tryToString()
```

What am I missing ?

Replying a comment I found correct words to my question.

**Why do we have to hand code  (/eclipse generated)   toString/hash/equals  which could have been done by Java compiler  ?**

Comment: Are you asking why Java doesn't provide a default `toString()` implementation for each class that doesn't provide one explicitly, analogously to how it provides a default public no-arg constructor for each class that doesn't provide any constructor?

Comment: Little different.  The public CTOR with no-arg, does nothing. I was questioning why do we have to hand code  (eclipse generate) a toString/hash/equals  which could have been done by Java compiler .

Comment: I think there is no good answer besides: when the language was invented; nobody thought about that. And as the other answer shows: it isn't easy to get a "default" implementation right. If you really want the compiler to do all such things for you; turn to scala and its value classes ;-)

Comment: @Jägermeister
Yes, I am getting closer and closer to picking up Scala as my default weapon. :)

Comment: @Ajeet just for completeness so that others do not misconstrue your comment.. scala does not generate toString on classes by default either, one has to declare the class a case class and then tune which fields are included/excluded by nature of how the fields are declared.  But yes, Scala is a decent language ;)

Answer (score 4):

1. Java is a very conservative language, to change the default behaviour after 20 years would change existing programs.  Which is something that is generally avoided in Java as much as possible.
2. If toString was to always return the value of every field then it opens a program up to two risks, a) the generated string could get very large, ie spam logs and b) get so so large due to a circular reference or big data that it would never end and cause a stack overflow or an out of memory exception (both can be avoided, by adding extra cost/complexity).
3. defaulting to a hash is not useless, as a default behaviour in a debugger it gives clues about object identity rather than equality.. useful for certain classes of bug.
4. Some fields may contain sensitive information, such as passwords or credit card numbers.  Such fields should not appear in full in logs.  (chrylis)

Comment: Also security risks if there's any sensitive information in the object.

Comment: Security risk and default behavior issues could be solved by using a marker interface similar to serializer. 
@Chris K :  Don't you think we have seen(may not be written) more bugs because of default implementation of hashcode instead of equality based hashcode ?